# Connecting To Amazon EC2 through separate WiFi at same time using Ethernet for HTTP Traffic

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, proxy

I am currently in a university Network which allows connection to **INTERNET** via **HTTP/HTTPS proxy** . which looks like 10.3.100.207:8080

All I needed is to connect to Amazon EC2 Instance via separate WiFi connection through ssh and using university INTERNET connection for HTTP browsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSH `ssh` have a switch `-b`, which allows you to specify to which local IP address it should bind when connecting to the remote host. There is also respective `BindAddress` option which you can store in your `ssh_config`.

Let's say your wireless IP address is `192.168.0.5` and remote host is `remote`, then you can

```
ssh -b 192.168.0.5 remote
```

or store a record in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host remote
  BindAddress 192.168.0.5
```

to make that working for you.

<sup>([duplicate question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800387/directing-ssh-to-use-wireless-instead-of-wired-network/800489#800489))</sup>